# telepresence like alternative in AWS ECS Farget Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, telepresence

I have been working with Kubernetes for container orchestration and I have been using `telepresence` for swapping deployments from local to dev cluster and works like a charm. This also helps me in testing and fast iterations as I do not have to build and wait for my code to be deployed to the dev cluster.

Recently I switched to ECS and I have been wondering if there is a way to swap services from ECS Farget dev cluster to service running locally on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such possibility. Here's a blog post regarding testing ECS containers locally:

[A Guide to Locally Testing Containers with Amazon ECS Local Endpoints and Docker Compose](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/a-guide-to-locally-testing-containers-with-amazon-ecs-local-endpoints-and-docker-compose/)

Comment: A slightly more up-to-date workflow (that leverages the same ECS local endpoints as well as a new ECS / compose integration) is described in [this more recent blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/). Check out the second example (brand new application) where I run the code on my laptop and use backend services in the cloud).